# Backup only yesterday's data from one table

Tags: mysql

I tried to research this but could not find anything, so I'm back to asking the collective.

In a fairly busy MySQL DB I have an access_log table which gets about 10 million records a day.  The goal is to get yesterday's records and move them to a different DB on a different server.  Is there a way to hot backup only yesterday's data from just that table?

Thank you for your input,
Kate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have just one access_log table, it's straightforward to select those records. You'll have to pull them into a client program then push them to another table.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM access_log
 WHERE logtime >= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
   AND logtime < CURRENT_DATE();
```

Then

```
DELETE
  FROM access_log
 WHERE logtime >= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
   AND logtime < CURRENT_DATE();
```

(Avoid the use of `BETWEEN` to select time/date ranges; it does the wrong thing at the end of the range you're selecting.)

But this is a bit of a performance pig. For one thing this table should use the MyISAM storage engine, not InnoDB, so you aren't saddled with transaction overhead.

If it is InnoDB and you can't change that, you may need to write a program to read and then delete the data in smaller chunks.  For example, one of the chunks might be:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM access_log
 WHERE logtime >= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
   AND logtime < CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 2 HOUR
```

Or, if you can afford a second or two of downtime at midnight you could rename the access_log table to yesterday_access_log, and create a new one for today. Then you can save yesterday's table without colliding with production performance.

You can do that midnight log-swap operation with statements like these:

```
CREATE TABLE `access_log_new` (
  /* whatever columns you have in your access_log table, I made this stuff up */
  `log_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `logtime` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`log_id`)
) ENGINE=MYISAM;
DROP TABLE access_log_old;  
RENAME TABLE access_log TO access_log_old;
RENAME TABLE access_log_new TO access_log;
```

The two last statements here, the `RENAME TABLE` statements, are very fast. There's a tiny period of time when there's no access_log table, but it's far less than a second.  The idea is to set everything up nicely, then quickly flip the log files.

That might be a really good strategy; it would let you use the cheap-to-write and expensive-to-search ARCHIVE storage engine for your live access_log table.

If you have the choice of restructuring your access_log table, you may choose to partition it by day so you can simply swap out the daily partition tables.  But that's a longer topic.

Comment: Ollie, thank you for your input and the additional ideas... I'm liking the concept of partitioning the table by day.  I did actually consider using two tables, but I cannot afford any downtime (there is a slow down at some time during the day but I would still lose thousands of entries); I also thought of swapping between the tables _0 and _1 based on date mod "(time() / (24*60*60)) % 2", however that would also be a performance pig but on the web server side (having to check the mod with each insert).

Comment: WHERE logtime >= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
   AND logtime < CURRENT_DATE();

can be written as date() between curdate() - interval 1 day and curdate() - interval 1 day

Comment: That's not an equivalent expression, @AdrianBR, unless the `date` column being compared doesn't have any times except midnight in it. If you mean `DATE(logtime)` using a function will defeat the use of an index on the `logtime` column, which is a bad thing in a large table.

Comment: ah gotcha Ollie, you were going for using index when field is timestamp. my mistake

Comment: Thanks again Ollie :)
Since I do have the option of somewhat restructuring the access_table (I can just start using a new one) I've been looking into the partitioning option and I'm liking that quite a bit as it will make moving the data (the partition) quite simple.  From there I just run my stats, and I think, since the data will be partitioned I will even not need to move anything into yet another archive table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do it by using the cron job.

Make cron job and write the queries to send the data to other database there.

Here is the example of cron job: http://docs.phplist.com/CronJobExamples.html

And here is the tutorial : http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT rows 
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/backup.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM test_table WHERE date=curdate()-1;
```

if you do not have a date, consider giving them an auto incremental id and split by id

Comment: I fear the WHERE clause you suggest won't work if the `date` column is a timestamp.

Comment: where date(timestamp)=curdate()-1